# Show by example that $A \ge B \ge 0 \implies A^2 \ge B^2 \ge 0$ is not true in general

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show by example that $A \ge B \ge 0 \implies A^2 \ge B^2 \ge 0$ is not true in general, where $A$ and $B$ are both $n \times n$ matrices in $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that if $AB=BA$, then $A \ge B \ge 0 \implies A^k \ge B^k \ge 0$ holds for $k=1,2,3, \cdots$.

So, the aim is to find such two matrices $A$ and $B$, $AB \ne BA$, and the proposition above dosen't hold.

Can anyone help me to find such a counterexample?

remark: here $A \ge B$ means that $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can consider the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 30&0\\0&6 \end{bmatrix},$ which is clearly positive definite (its eigenvalues are $6,30$) and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 5&4\\4&5 \end{bmatrix},$ with eigenvalues $1,9,$ which make $B$ positive definite. Then:
$$A-B=\begin{bmatrix} 25&-4\\-4&1 \end{bmatrix},$$ with eigenvalues $0.3509$ and $25.6491,$ thus $A-B$ is positive definite, but:
$$A^2- B^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 859&-40\\-40&-5 \end{bmatrix},$$ has eigenvalues $-6.8479$ and $860.8479,$ thus $A^2-B^2$ is **not** positive semi-definite.

---

**Remark:** In order to find such suitable matrices I started with a matrix $A$ of the form $\begin{bmatrix}C&0\\0&D \end{bmatrix}$ and a matrix $B$ of the form $\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$ and tried to apply the constraints in order to find suitable $C,D,a,b.$

Comment: very instructive answer!

Comment: @VictorChen Thank you, though I did not search thoroughly to see if I can reach any general result.