# $A,B$ positive semidefinite matrices with $A \geq B$ implies $A^2 \geq B^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Is it true that if I am considering positive semidefinite matrices $A, B$ with $A \geq B$ then $A^2 \geq B^2$?
Could you help me prove this or think of a counterexample (eventually assuming the simmetricity of the matrices)?

Edit: by $A \geq B$ I mean that $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Please edit to clarify what $A\geq B$ means in this context.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854787/show-by-example-that-a-ge-b-ge-0-implies-a2-ge-b2-ge-0-is-not-true-in-g/1854863#1854863